# ngDialog contents not clickable?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-dialog

I am using ngDialog dialog box for my mean.js application with the following call :

```
 ngDialog.open({
                template: 'modules/users/views/userDetails/dialog.client.view.html',
                scope: $scope,
                closeByDocument :false
            });
```

Now, the dialog is opening fine and all the elements in it are also visible.
But I am not able to perform any any action on them.i.e., click a button or type in a text field. It feels like the whole dialog box is out of focus.

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Note : Angular Animate might be disabled in my application by the following code :

```
$timeout(function () {
            return $animate.enabled(false, angular.element(".carousel"));
        });
```

But, the above code is in another controller.

Could this be the reason for the failure?

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: Maybe there is a div or something on top of your controls and when you think you click a button you actually click the div and nothing happens in this case.

Comment: i'm having the exact same problem. But when i set "overlay" to false, then i am able to click on it again. The only issue with this solution is that the parent window no longer becomes dark and is clickable again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the css a bit:

```
.ngdialog-overlay {
    z-index: -1;
}
```